# auto query suggestor based on past query history

Tags: solr, elasticsearch

In both elastic search or solr, are there methods that support auto query suggestor based on past query history?
Basically, whenever I type a query, I want to have a drop down list to suggest me a list of queries based on my search history.

Answer (score 1):

You are combining autosuggest and recent search field. What solr provides is autosuggest based on your search word and the existing data.

And solr do not provide recent search feature. You have to maintain a separate database of the query terms used recently and then show them. You can also use cookies. This feature is entirely at the web application level, and solr have nothing to do with it.

So you are combining the above 2 things here - "autosuggest based on past query". Please understand the requirement and features provided by the framwork, then you will get the answer yourself. happy Learning

Comment: This is a feature many people would use.  If you want to take the localstorage route (search history stored in browser), please consider forking and enhancing [typeahead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/).  If you want a persistent server-side solution, look into contributing an [Elasticsearch plugin](https://www.found.no/foundation/writing-a-plugin/).

Answer (score 0):

The SuggestComponent in Solr provides users with automatic suggestions for query terms. You can use this to implement a powerful auto-suggest feature in your search application.

Although it is possible to use the Spell Checking functionality to power autosuggest behavior, Solr has a dedicated SuggestComponent designed for this functionality. This approach utilizes Lucene's Suggester implementation and supports all of the lookup implementations available in Lucene.

The first step is to add a search component to solrconfig.xml to extend the SpellChecker. Here is some sample code that could be used.

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
    <lst name="suggester">
        <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
        <str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
        <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
        <str name="field">cat</str>
        <str name="weightField">price</str>
        <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">string</str>
        <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
    </lst>
</searchComponent>
```

Adding the Suggest Request Handler

```
<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="suggest">true</str>
        <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
        <str>suggest</str>
    </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

These above configuration are given from Solr 5.2.0 documentation.

Comment: how could I suggest matching query based on "PAST QUERY HISTORY"?

Comment: Do you mean query history of individual users or all the query search made to application ?

Comment: One could use this approach as long as what is indexed in solr is not the document collection, but the searches collection, using a weight equal to the amount of times the search appeared :)